# How to define new equation counter in footnote?

Tags: equations, footnotes, counters

I want to have two equation counter format for normal equations in text and in footnote as follows:

[image]

I think best way is to redefine footnote equations, but I don't know how do it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please give a use case for wanting to assign a number to a displayed equation in a footnote.

Comment: `\footnote` is no environment and is this really useful, to hide 'important' equations in footnotes?

Comment: for example F.thesection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I doubt the usefulness of a specific counter for equations in a footnote (or numbered equations in a footnote at all), but here's a quick hack, by hijacking the `\footnote` code and temporarily setting the `\c@equation` and `\theequation` macros to `\c@footequation` and `\thefootequation`, in a group.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{letltxmacro}

\usepackage{xparse}

\newcounter{footequation}[section]

\renewcommand{\thefootequation}{F.\arabic{footequation}}
\makeatletter
\LetLtxMacro\latex@@footnote\footnote
\RenewDocumentCommand{\footnote}{om}{%
  \begingroup
  \let\c@equation\c@footequation
  \let\theequation\thefootequation
  \IfValueTF{#1}{%
    \latex@@footnote[#1]{#2}%
  }{%
    \latex@@footnote{#2}%
  }%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  E=mc^{2} \label{foo}
\end{equation} 

See \eqref{footeq}

Some text\footnote{\begin{equation}E=mc^{2}\label{footeq}\end{equation}}

\begin{equation}
  c^{2}=a^{2} + b^{2} \label{pythagoras}
\end{equation} 

Some text\footnote{\begin{equation} c^{2}=a^{2} + b^{2}\label{footpythagoras}\end{equation}}

\end{document}
```

[image]